# Issues with HTTPoison.post

Tags: elixir

I use Poloniex API to make my trades for long time.
My previous version was coded in bash shell script. Now, I'm doing the code in Elixir.

The issue I'm facing now is related to API refusing my commands.
Look this test. **Nonce will be repeated just to see if the same signature is generated**.

**Bash**

```
tapiurl: https://poloniex.com/tradingApi
postdata: command=returnBalances&nonce=1455742931958817
sign: 340970c8dc8b2f50c2772b2edf45297d7c3758c922192a5fbbae82c70b3b408dab5f652d23e25a8e6bf7fd687ff18f02f36ffbc5b71d496298af33c5ffc73291
command: curl -iv -H "Key: $apikey" -H "Sign: $sign" -d "$postdata" $tapiurl
Result is okay:
{"1CR":"0.00000000","ABY":"0.00000000"....
```

Now, look the same postdata and sign on Elixir.

**Elixir**

```
tapiurl = "https://poloniex.com/tradingApi"
nonce = :os.system_time(:micro_seconds)
data = %{command: "returnBalances", nonce: nonce}
postdata = URI.encode_query(data)
sign = Base.encode16(:crypto.hmac(:sha512, apisecret, postdata), case: :lower)
headers = [Key: apikey, Sign: sign]
HTTPoison.post(tapiurl, postdata, headers)

Result: "{\"error\":\"Invalid command.\"}"
```

As you can see, I'm sending the same data in both languages, so why I'm getting "Invalid command"?
The same nonce is just an example, to check if the same signature is being generated.
I know I have to use always different nonces.

Comment: Your code block named "Elixir" does not contain valid elixir code, so I have to guess here. I suspect you are giving HTTPoison the wrong arguments. See https://github.com/edgurgel/httpoison/blob/master/test/httpoison_test.exs#L42 for an example of how to POST urlencoded form data.

Comment: Yes, adding actual code as opposed to just those values that you think are important would help a lot with suggesting an answer to you.

Comment: Code added as requested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Poloniex API expects the `content-type` header to be set.

Try this:

```
headers = [Key: apikey, Sign: sign, "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"]
```

Comment: Works better this way. I do not have to pass `{:form, postdata}`. Works fine with `HTTPoison.post(tapiurl, postdata, headers)` if content-type speified on headers. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
postdata = [command: "returnBalances", nonce: nonce]
HTTPoison.post(tapiurl, {:form, postdata})
```

Besides some API endpoint expect JSON-encoded string instead of separate post params. In that cases `Poison.encode!(postdata)` could be used.

Comment: Hi. Poloniex expects separate POST params. The bash shell command works fine: `curl -iv -H "Key: $apikey" -H "Sign: $sign" -d "$postdata" $tapiurl`. `postdata` already being sent that way, but encoded in querystring. Take a look at the updated Elixir code block.

Comment: Well, how about `HTTPoison.post(tapiurl, {:form, [command: "returnBalances", nonce: nonce]})` ?

Comment: Works in that way @roman-smirnov. Thanks! Now, I have to accept your answer. Can you edit it to include the answer?

Comment: Roman, your answer is right, but Gazler answer is more clear. Thank you anyway.